# Django error external IP on production server

Tags: django

On my production server I keep getting errors similar to this one

`[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 't17.proxy-checks.com:443'. You may need to add 't17.proxy-checks.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

I don't know why and how this error is coming. Should I ignore these error messages ?

I've added my domain and private IP to the allowed hosts in the settings.py file. I want to know what exactly is this error, are these bots? And whether it's safe to ignore them

Comment: are you running your web server behind a proxy or load balancer? i believe this is true

Comment: No I'm simply using Apache to serve my project

Comment: I was using Elastic beanstalk with uWSGI server and load balancer in front of  web server. Load balancer redirect request with dynamic IPs each time. Another reason was EB was sending request to my  app to check app health. These are the 2 common reasons if you are using services like Elastic beanstalk. Where you have deployed your app for production?

Comment: It's on Amazon ec2

Comment: check answer and see if this is  helps

Answer (score 1):

I was using Elastic beanstalk with uWSGI server and load balancer in front of web server. Load balancer redirect requests with dynamic IPs each time. Another reason was, EB was sending request to my app to check app health. These are the 2 common reasons if you are using services like Elastic beanstalk or EC2.

To ignore such errors from sending to ADMINS or logs, i tried this and it worked.

Check [Django Docs on this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-security) for more details

`settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'include_html': True,
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'console': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },

        # Don't send invalid host error messages to ADMINS.
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-security
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'admins': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

If you don't want to even forward this error to log, move `django.security.DisallowedHost` to the top of `loggers`. Right now this will move to log but not to ADMINS as `propagate=False`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will stop the errors from reporting on my admin email. But is it safe to ignore this error? Because I receive this error from unknown domains and ip addresses.

Comment: I think this is safe in terms of any harm to your application. This exception raise when django is going to create `HttpRequest` object after calling `wsgi.py`, which will later pass into its respective `view`. So this doesn't hit any `views` or `models` etc.  it breaks on `request.get_host()`



[Source code of raising this exception](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L100)

Comment: `when an HTTP Host header is included in a request from a client that does not match ALLOWED_HOSTS, Django will return a 400 response, and an error message will be logged to the django.security.DisallowedHost logger.` from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-security)

Answer (score 0):

in the settings of django `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` or something like this `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['t17.proxy-checks.com']`
[ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: if you do not want to store in the settings, ```t17.proxy-checks.com```, i think then you can pull it up with environments

Comment: No actually I'm more concerned about why this error is coming as it's not my domain or private IP? I've already added the necessary in the allowed hosts

Comment: I will cant say whether it's safe to ignore this, but here's some more info on this :)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#host-header-validation

Comment: Thanks a lot pasha